# How to solve stop watch error using js?

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I am trying to make a java script timer.But I am facing some simple problem.First one is when I start time,it start with 1 in second section but I want to start it some like 01.Same problem in minute section too.Also there's is another problem in minute section is that,after getting the number 59,hour is'not increasing.

Here is my js code line

```
var digit=00;
var hrs = 00;
var min=00;
var time;
var timer_is_on=0;

function timer(){
    document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML=digit;
    digit=digit+1;
    digit = parseInt(digit);
    time=setTimeout("timer()",1000);
    if(digit>"59"){

        min=parseInt(min)+1;
        var count = min.toString().length;
        document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML=min;
        digit=0;
    }
    if(digit>"59"){
        hrs=parseInt(hrs)+1
        document.getElementById("hrs").innerHTML=hrs;
        digit=0;
    }
}

    function activate(){
    if(!timer_is_on){
        timer_is_on=1;
        timer();
    }
}
```

Here is my HTML code :

```
<a href="#" onclick="activate()">Click here to start the timer</a>
<span id="hrs" >00</span>:<span id="mins" >00</span>:<span id="secs">00</span>
```

My working demo is here : http://jsfiddle.net/rFTzL/1/
Also I need to set stop time by clicking same start button.Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few issues in your code. Try this . added comments as well

```
            var digit=0;
    var hrs = 0;
    var min=0;
    var time;
    var timer_is_on=0;

    function timer(){
        //[Old] - this should be placed after you increment digit
        // document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML = digit

        //[New]
        // get the numerical value for seconds,minutes,hours
        digit = parseInt(document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML);
        min   = parseInt(document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML);
        hrs   = parseInt(document.getElementById("hrs").innerHTML);
        // increment;
        digit=digit+1;    


        if(digit>"59"){

            min = parseInt(min)+1;
            // why is this code here
            var count = min.toString().length;


            digit=0;
        }
        // [old] checking if second is greater than 59 and incrementing hours
        // if(digit>"59"){

        // [new] check if minute is greater than 59
        if(min > "59"){
            hrs=parseInt(hrs)+1;        
            digit=0;
            min=0; // minute should be reset as well
        }


         // set the values after all processing is done
        document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML = format(digit);
        document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML= format(min);
        document.getElementById("hrs").innerHTML=format(hrs);

    }

        function activate(){
        if(!timer_is_on){
            timer_is_on=1;
            // time = setTimeout("timer()",1000) will only call it once , use setInterval instead
            time=setInterval("timer()",1000);
        }
        else {
            timer_is_on=0;
            clearInterval(time); // clear the timer when the user presses the button again and reset timer_is_on
        }
    }

    // left pad zero if it is less than 9
    function format(time){
        if(time > 9)
            return time;
        else return "0"+time;
    }
```

Comment: Its working fine,but can I place it in multiple anchor tag,suppose I have two another to display the clock.In that case,If I clicked second one,first one will stop and second one will start clock from 0.How can I do this?Any Idea? @user63363

Comment: yes you can . you can also use the same function but you will have to make a modification. you will need to reset the values in hours,mins and seconds span elements.

Comment: if the answer is correct , please mark it as a correct answer

Comment: can you provide me timer for multiple anchor please,It will help me lot.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution http://jsfiddle.net/rFTzL/3/

```
var digit=00;

var hrs = 00;
var min=00;
var time;
var timer_is_on=0;

function timer(){
    document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML=("0" +digit).slice(-2);
    digit=digit+1;
    digit = parseInt(digit);
    
    if(digit>59){
        
        min=parseInt(min)+1;
        var count = min.toString().length;
        document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML=("0"+min).slice(-2);
        digit=0;
    }
    if(min>59){
        hrs=parseInt(hrs)+1
        document.getElementById("hrs").innerHTML=("0"+hrs).slice(-2);
        digit=0;
    }
}


    function activate(){
    if(!timer_is_on){
        timer_is_on=1;
        time=setInterval("timer()",1000);
    }else{
        clearInterval(time);
                timer_is_on=0;
    }
}
```

It will stop the watch also.
There was one issue that you have to use min instead of digit for updating hours.

Comment: Its not working properly.Please increase setinterval value from 1000 to 10001223344576878879656564545454545343423323224354568787878787,than see the output after 59 minutes.Hours portion is not working properly